# Getting the DNS IP used within an AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-cli, vpc

Is there an awscli command with which you can get the DNS server to be used for a VPS? Or is this a static IP address on all Amazon instance? I'm unable to find any reference, except that the IP address is passed via DHCP for EC2 nodes. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you see [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html#AmazonDNS)?

Comment: That does only expose changes in the default right? If I do not create a new Set, it does not allow me to query the current options, afaict.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what are you asking.

Comment: I created a VPC with a NAT gateway, but I need to set the DNS manually, by getting the nameserver IP address. This is set automatically by AWS, but the only way to get it seems to be the DHCP options that are transmitted. I was hoping I could get it from awscli as well.

Comment: I still don't get it but let's try, run this on your instance: `cidr=$(curl -s -S http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/$(curl -s -S http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/mac)/vpc-ipv4-cidr-block | cut -f 1 -d '/') && [[ "$cidr" =~ ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.)([0-9]+)$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]+2}`, the output should be the address of your instance's DNS server

Comment: I know how to get it from within the instance :) I want to get it from outside the instance with hopefully the aws cli.